# Как разместить div'ы

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу чтобы div'ы располагались также, внутри другого div'a, который имеет ширину и высоту.
Это должно происходить автоматически, допустим php создает несколько div, и они автоматически должны расположиться

Помогите, я не представляю как это сделать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

примените для родительского div'a:

```
.parent {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но отступ по высоте слишком большой, это можно исправить?

Comment: можно, но нужно видеть ваши стили для этого.